# Condensed cream of mushroom over chicken and rice

Tags: chicken, rice, mushrooms

I was thinking about doing a baked dish with chicen and rice covered with a can of cream of mushroom soup.  I'd like some advice.

I was just planning on kinda winging it by cooking some rice, putting it in a casserole dish, placing some chicken breast on top, then covering it with the soup and baking until chicken is done.  maybe put some bread crumbs on top so they get nice and brown.

Any tips before I try it out?

Comment: I used to do a recipe with condensed mushroom soup mixed with sausages and pasta, covered with grated cheddar and baked.  It was great.  Baking the rice doesn't sound ideal to me, I think I would partially cook the breast, fry some mushrooms, put them in a pot with the soup and cook through, then pour over cooked rice.

Comment: Don't season your rice! Your condensed soup is going to be extremely salty, even more so once it's been condensed in the oven. Other than that, it sounds like every quick casserole I ever ate growing up, not mind-blowing, but some great comfort food.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of tips:

- When you cook the rice, make sure it's not too soggy, or it won't absorb the flavour of the chicken and soup.
- Make sure to liquefy the soup before pouring it over top or it will glop more than pour - especially if you don't plan to mix it with water or milk. Put it in a bowl and mash it until it's liquid enough to pour.
- (probably obvious) For safety, make sure to fully cook the dish (especially the chicken) before taste-testing!

You could also try a ready-to-serve (non-condensed) soup. This usually isn't as gelatinous as condensed soup.

Answer (score 2):

Sound fine, but in my experience "cream if mushroom" soup in a can is not much mushroom, and a lot of thickener

If you want something real nice, and not too much work make a Duxelles (fine chopped mushroom stuffing) and stuff it under the chicken's skin (works best with legs). Cover the rice with either mushroom soup or crushed tomato and tomato juice mix, then chicken on top and bake

[Example recipe for chicken part](http://www.chicken-breast-recipes.biz/chicken-breast-with-mushroon-duxelles-recipe/) ignore sauce part for a rice bake

Comment: Looks like a tasty recipe! I'll have to try it sometime soon.

Answer (score 0):

Add garlic and/or onions

(a spoon from a jar of garlic paste in the fridge is very easy).

Comment: I always forget about jars of minced garlic and the like.  I usually end up just using garlic powder because I don't feel like messing with chopping a clove.  Yum Garlic!

Comment: Garlic powder (or indeed onion powder or onion soup mix) also works great in a case like this. For a cheap and simple casserole or stew, buying and preparing fresh garlic cloves is just silly.

Answer (score 0):

are you using instant rice, brown rice, long-grain? it will make a difference in cooking times and techniques.

my mom used to make a dish when i was a kid that was on the back of the instant rice box, it sounds similar to what you're looking for: brown chicken breasts in a skillet & set aside, then add a can of cream of mushroom soup and two cans of water. bring to a boil, add 2 c. rice and the chicken, cook covered for about 5 min. she'd then transfer to a casserole dish, top with cheese, and broil it to make the cheese crispy. yum.